# How to define the math operator in n//m?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[I reworded the question to make it less based on opinion and ask only for specific expertise.]

Using Sage one can write m//n for the integer division. I found Sage's notation very convenient to use and want to use this notation also with TeX. What is the best way to do so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\+{/ \mkern-5mu /}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a_{n}&=2^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}\left(\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor+1\right) n!
\\[6pt] 
a_{n}&=2^{n/\!/2}\left(n/\!/2+1\right) n!
\\[6pt]
a_{n}&=2^{n\+2}\left(n\+2+1\right) n!
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personally I prefer `n\m`, (I can't think which programming language I first came across this notation in, but it stuck) but surely it's a matter of using whatever notation is standard in your field.

Comment: I mean a notation which has the potential to _become_ standard in mathematical writings. Note that // is a unicode character (U+20EB) and is already supported by the STIX fonts.

Comment: I think this is an entirely opinion based question. I've seen the notation `\lfloor n/2\rfloor` to be replaced sometimes with the use of the `div` keyword (just like the `mod` keyword). I think `\lfloor n/2\rfloor` IS the common notation in mathematical writings.

Comment: Note that U+20EB is a combining character; the character you're referring to is U+2AFD DOUBLE SOLIDUS OPERATOR. In `unicode-math` it's `\sslash`

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the spacing between the slashes given by the spacing of a dot. This makes it quite well scalable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\+{\mathbin{\mathrlap{/}\phantom{.}/}}
\newcommand\aLtErNaTiVe{\mathord{\mathrlap{/}\phantom{.}/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a_{n}&=2^{n\+2}(n\+2+1) n!
\\
a_{n}&=2^{n\aLtErNaTiVe 2}(n\aLtErNaTiVe 2+1) n!
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I certainly prefer the "loose" spacing like any binary operator has. You can prefer the "tight" spacing like the slash has, but it seems not to be quite proper here.